# How to display selection effect QLineEdit in QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I want to display selection effect QLineEdit in QTableWidget, like QTableWidgetItem.

I've tried to find that by qss, but not found.

Below is an example

(1)[image]
(2)[image]

Comment: Do you want to highlight a QLineEdit when you click on it, like a table widget does when you click on a cell within the table?

Comment: @Rhdr Yes, I want to highlight a QLineEdit !! I have to use QLineEdit for QCompleter.

Comment: @Tae please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc sry I'll try that